# How to indicate to Visual studio where third party dll source code is?

Tags: debugging, dll, c++-cli, visual-studio-debugging, native-code

I am writing a C++/CLI for a C library. I have the source code of the library. When I launch a debug session, I can't step into the C dll, VS says that the source code is not available. So how do I tell VS where it is?
Thank you... I've tried pointing Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols to add the folder where the pdb is but it changed nothing.
Regards

**SOLVED**:
Turns out I needed to copy the dll and .pdb files to the Debug folder of my C# project calling the C++/CLI dll.

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, put it as an answer and a day or two later accept it. That way this question goes into the solved list, and others can benefit from it.

Comment: Hi. I know but my reputation is not yet good enough to answer my own questions under 8 hours

Comment: I think that goes for everybody. You have to wait a bit before you can accept your own answer. Not sure.

Comment: I have to wait a bit to post it :)... Then wait some more to accept it